# C# wpf slider value and Text box

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, slider

I am working with one text box, slider. I need help about some code. I am trying to make a program that it work like this, when i decide what value is going to have slider , i write it in text box, and slider value update automatically. Every thing is fine, but when i try to put another values, then is showed the message "input string was not in a correct format". the code is under:

```
<Slider Margin="0,10,0,0" TickPlacement="BottomRight" TickFrequency="10" Name="SL2" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"/>
<TextBox Name="txtslider2" Height="30" Width="150" Margin="45,10,0,0" TextChanged="txtslider2_TextChanged" />
<Label Name="lblslider2" Content= Slider II" Height="30" Width="130" Margin="-220,-30,10,0"/>



private void txtslider2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
  SL2.Value = SL2.Value + int.Parse(txtslider2.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<StackPanel>
<Slider x:Name="SL2" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding ElementName=txtslider2, Path=text}" />
<TextBox x:Name="txtslider2" Text="{Binding ElementName=SL2, Path=Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Label Content="Slider II"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and remove txtslider2_TextChanged function

UPD1: Add UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in TextBox>Text>Binding

Answer (score 0):

**Try this in code behind:**

```
 private void txtslider2_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
            {                
                    string val = (txtslider2.Text != "") ? txtslider2.Text : "0";
                    SL2.Value = int.Parse(val);                
            }
```